# Imagemagick replace all colors in image with white

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of PNG images (logos) that I want to convert to an all-white color pallet; basically I want to replace all non-transparent pixels with white pixels. Is there an easy way to do this in imagemagick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick using -colorize.

```
convert input.png -fill white -colorize 100 output.png
```

It will preserve the transparent pixels and make everything else white.