# Convert all opaque pixels to white, keeping transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of png drawings with slightly varying colors and alphas on a transparent background.

I want to convert the non-fully transparent pixels to white, keeping the local alpha. In Photoshop I can do this by clicking the "Lock transparent pixels" icon, then filling the entire image with white.

I'd like to automate this process and thought of using ImageMagick in Ubuntu (running on my Windows 10's WSL; `convert -version` is 6.9.10.)

I have been googling for a while without luck, so far. Found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270581/imagemagick-replace-all-colors-in-image-with-white), but it's not working for me, it bails out with the following error and produces an all-white image:

```
convert-im6.q16: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `out.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1667.
```

Elsewhere I found that the `-strip` flag can suppress this warning, however the output is still an all-white image.

Interestingly, if I specify a non-white color, the result is almost what I need, except of course the colors won't be white. (e.g. `convert original.png -fill yellow -colorize 100 out.png`)

Comment: Can you provide representative input and corresponding expected output example images please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a true PEBKAC situation. I only needed the `-strip` flag, because what I thought to be all-white images were in fact correctly painted to white with their original transparency data preserved, only the image thumbnails were incorrectly generated on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want in ImageMagick 6. Use -fill and +opaque.

Transparent Image:

[image]

```
convert logot.png -fill white +opaque none logot_white.png
```

[image]

You will have to download each image to see what is transparent, since this forum uses a white background color.

If on Imagemagick 7, change "convert" to "magick"

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I'm still getting a full white image (and had to use the `-strip` flag too, otherwise I got the mentioned RGB color space error) when I was using my own image (that I've exported as PNG from Affinity Designer), but your suggestion was working as you described with the image you've provided. Very strange.

Comment: You could post your image if you want me to examine it.

Comment: Turned out I was completely wrong and failed to notice that only the generated thumbnail was showing up as all white, and the conversion was successful even with my initial attempt, once I provided the strip flag. It works with your solution too.